# Installing Google Earth in a 64-bit system

Tags: package-management, software-installation, google-earth

ok. solved the problem with lib-core now I get this error.

```
jacob@jacob-desktop:~$ sudo -s dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-earth-stable.
(Reading database ... 173493 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-earth-stable (from google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-earth-stable:
 google-earth-stable depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing google-earth-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-earth-stable
```

when I try to install ia32-libs ubuntu tells me it has been replaced with other packages. advice??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the 32-bits version. A bunch of 64-bits versions of non-multiarch packages. The best way is to install the 32-bit version:

```
wget http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
sudo gdebi google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Comment: does the 64bit version run on ubuntu?

Comment: simple answer: no.

Comment: thanks seems to have worked. one more thing...is the 32bit version stable? i had problems with an older version on ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: the package is called google-earth-**stable_current**. I don't know until what state it's stable but it's stable as far as google goes. If my answer helped please mark it as accepted then.

Comment: i got it installed but it won't run when i click on the icon. any advice on this?

Comment: sorry, no idea, I only use the online version... OpenGl and my system don't play well together. I remember another guy in chat that had the same problem. If you ask a question explaining the problem and what happened the better. Also the output of running it in the terminal would be helpful.